# AngularJS Routing not loading ui-view

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess

When I hit my site I dont see the ui-view loading my partial, I first thought it was the htaccess but then realised that when I hit mysite:8080/#/login is still doesn't load the ui-view which is empty. PLEASE HELP :(

CODE

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function($stateProvider,$httpProvider,$locationProvider){ 

    $stateProvider.state('_login',{
       url:'/',
       templateUrl:'partial/login/login.html',
       controller:'loginController'
    }).state('home',{
        url:'/home',
        templateUrl:'partial/home/home.html',
        controller:'homeController'
    }).state('logout',{
       url:'/logout',
       templateUrl:'partial/logout/logout.html',
       controller:'logoutController'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}).run(function($window,$state,$rootScope){     

   $state.go('login');

});
```

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

Comment: As you can see from the various answers, you had multiple issues with your code.  Apparently, you haven't given us enough code to get to your posted issue.  Why don't you add more of your code to your question, preferably in the form of a functioning snippet, JsFiddle, or Plunker?  Otherwise, I don't think we are going to get to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject ui-router into your module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
   .config(function($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider){
```

Comment: Let me give it a try and confirm

Comment: Hi jBrown, I've added this in already look like this angular.module('myApp',['ui.router','ngResource','myApp.controllers','myApp.services']);

Answer (score 0):

You want to navigate to the "login" state, however you have defined above as state "_login".

Comment: Hi yes I have fixed that still get the same error. :(

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When you define url in optional params then it matches url like a regular expression for the given state, so your state should be like this for a this url mysite:8080/#/login

```
 $stateProvider.state('login',{
   url:'/login',
   templateUrl:'partial/login/login.html',
   controller:'loginController'
})
```